# Calculator for newbs

Tags: vb.net

I'm working on a calculator in which I want to get some numbers on a circle.

```
Private Sub Button6_Click(
    ByVal sender As System.Object, 
    ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click   

    Dim radius As Integer = TextBox13.Text
    Dim diameter As Integer = TextBox14.Text
    Dim length As Integer = TextBox15.Text
    
    TextBox13.Text = diameter / 2
    TextBox14.Text = radius * 2
    TextBox15.Text = radius * 2 * Math.PI
    TextBox15.Text = diameter * Math.PI
End Sub
```

That is the current code, but I'm experiencing a problem with "the number must be less than infinity".

Note: I'm a COMPLETE noob.

Comment: What line are you getting the error on? What are the values of all relevant variables? Why are you setting the text of `TextBox15` twice?

Comment: Make Option Strict On the first line of your program.  Use Integer.TryParse and .ToString to fix the errors.  This will help you  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff361664%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The error lies in the fact that you tried to assign an integer value of type string.
 Use the method provided by struct TryParse integer, this will also run in any runtime exception FormatException bran and do not send the application.

Here's an example:

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim diameter As Integer = 0
    Dim radius As Integer = 0
    Dim lenght As Integer = 0

    If Integer.TryParse(Me.TextBox13.Text, diameter) Then
        'your code 
    End If

    If Integer.TryParse(Me.TextBox14.Text, radius) Then
        'your code 
    End If

    If Integer.TryParse(Me.TextBox15.Text, lenght) Then
        'your code 
    End If
End Sub
```

More information about TryParse at this link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/f02979c7.aspx

Bye

Answer (score 0):

See if this works:

```
   Dim radius As Integer = Integer.Parse(TextBox13.Text)
   Dim diameter As Integer = Integer.Parse(TextBox14.Text)     
   Dim length As Integer = Integer.Parse(TextBox15.Text)
```

Comment: Dim diameter As Integer = Integer.Parse(TextBox14.Text) is where the error accours.. But thanks!

Comment: What value do you have for TextBox14.Text?  Integers need to be whole numbers without fraction i.e.  0, -100.  If you have a number with a decimal point, you should not use Integers.